# c++ separation steering algorithm showing weird results

Tags: c++, 2d, 2d-games

I'm implementing a simple separation steering algorithm (for axis aligned 2D rectangles).
The algorithm:

- For each rectangle (cell), check all others for overlap
- if overlaps, calculate difference in position vectors (vector points to top left corner of rectangle)
- add to total vector

in the end, force (acceleration) in applied in the opposite direction of the total vector, and the rectangle position is updated with each frame.

This is the separation logic:

```
bool Cell::seperateFrom(CellsContainer& cells) {
    Vector2D force_sum;
    int neighbor_count = 0;
    for (auto& other : cells) {
        if (!(*this == other) && this->overlaps(other)) {
            Vector2D position_diff = this->position - other.position;
            //normalize
            position_diff /= (float)sqrt(std::pow(position_diff.x,2) + std::pow(position_diff.y,2));
            force_sum += position_diff;
            neighbor_count++;
        }
    }
    if (neighbor_count > 0) {
      // calculate steer away vector;
      Vector2D steering = force_sum - this->velocity;
      //normalize
      steering /= (float) sqrt(std::pow(steering.x,2) + std::pow(steering.y,2));
      //move by tile size units
      steering *= static_cast<float> (TILE_SIZE);
      this->addForce(steering);
      return true;
    } else {
        // not overlapping, stop moving
        this->velocity *= 0.0f;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I start with randomly generated rectangles closely packed and it looks like separation is working, however the result is very directional and not very uniform by rectangle size (as seen below), and I don't understand why.

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

updatePosition function:

```
void Cell::updatePosition() {
    this->velocity += this->acceleration;
    this->position += this->velocity;
    this->rectangle.setPosition(this->position);
    this->acceleration *= 0.0f;
}
```

addForce:

```
  void addForce(const Vector2D& force)              {this->acceleration += force;}
```

Main Loop:

```
void main_loop(WindowType& window, CellsContainer& cells) {
    while (true) {
        window.clear();
        for (auto& cell_obj : cells) {
            cell_obj.seperateFrom(cells);
            cell_obj.updatePosition();
            window.draw(cell_obj.getRectangle());
        }
        window.display();    
    }
}
```

Comment: This could have to do with the order of the rectangles in the container.  Does `addForce` alter the position?

Comment: addForce() updates the acceleration vector. The main loop separates, updates position, and draws indefinitely for each cell. (not shown)

Comment: Please show the main loop code where you update the positions (as well as `addForce`). The problem seems rather systematic - larger rectangles are being pushed away further than the smaller ones.